# AWS route 53: If I want to use external server do I need to change SOA & NS records?

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

If I want to point to a server not in AWS,

Do I need to change the SOA & NS records that are created automatically (by route 53) ?

Thanks

Rafael.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, just create an A record (or whatever you need) and point it against the server you want.